# iTerm2 wrong color output

Tags: iterm, color

The command `ls` when using iTerm is behaving strange. It outputs colors but they change at some point and I don't think this is the normal behavior. I have the following alias for ls `alias ls='ls -FGlh'`. I'm also using the solarized-dark profile from [here](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). The result is as shown in the figure.[image]

Comment: almost looks like an issue with escape sequences maybe? Does iTerm2 support traditional POSIX escape sequences? Seems like a dumb question, but there might be a compatibility option somewhere.

Comment: I have no idea about that, I checked in the preferences and there's nothing related to POSIX. Any ideas on how I can check?

Comment: try this `echo -e "\033[1;32mHEYO\033[m HI"` and see what appears, should be one colored HEYO with an uncolored hi next to it (that's what works on a little linux system, it should work on OSX though too)

Comment: Yes, [I get that](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2346283/test.png).

Comment: I think your LS_COLORS might be funky, because the ls pic from above looks like ls forgot to end it's output with an end sequence. I don't use iterm2, but you can try to look up setting your LS_COLORS variables on OSX using dircolors. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @alexhairyman thanks a lot. I'll try to play with that variable later.

Comment: I removed the definition of `LSCOLORS` from the `.bashrc` file and the problem persists... =/